# Use pivot with out using agregate function in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot

I have this sample date in my table:

```
secq     dt              WORK_WEEK
----------------------------------
101 2021-01-04 12:00:00 2101
102 2021-01-05 12:00:00 2101
103 2021-01-06 12:00:00 2101
104 2021-01-07 12:00:00 2101
105 2021-01-08 12:00:00 2101
106 2021-01-09 12:00:00 2101
107 2021-01-10 12:00:00 2101
108 2021-01-11 12:00:00 2102
109 2021-01-12 12:00:00 2102
110 2021-01-13 12:00:00 2102
111 2021-01-14 12:00:00 2102
112 2021-01-15 12:00:00 2102
113 2021-01-16 12:00:00 2102
114 2021-01-17 12:00:00 2102
115 2021-01-18 12:00:00 2103
116 2021-01-19 12:00:00 2103
117 2021-01-20 12:00:00 2103
118 2021-01-21 12:00:00 2103
119 2021-01-22 12:00:00 2103
120 2021-01-23 12:00:00 2103
121 2021-01-24 12:00:00 2103
122 2021-01-25 12:00:00 2104
123 2021-01-26 12:00:00 2104
124 2021-01-27 12:00:00 2104
125 2021-01-28 12:00:00 2104
126 2021-01-29 12:00:00 2104
127 2021-01-30 12:00:00 2104
128 2021-01-31 12:00:00 2104
129 2021-02-01 12:00:00 2105
130 2021-02-02 12:00:00 2105
131 2021-02-03 12:00:00 2105
132 2021-02-04 12:00:00 2105
133 2021-02-05 12:00:00 2105
134 2021-02-06 12:00:00 2105
135 2021-02-07 12:00:00 2105
```

I want to display all dates only each work week I'm unable to produce the output

It should be like this:

[image: expected out put]

Here's what I have tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT DT, WORK_WEEK  
     FROM RP_CALENDAR
     WHERE YEAR = '2021')
 PIVOT 
     (MAX(dt) 
         FOR WORK_WEEK IN ('2101', '2102', '2103', '2105') 
     )
```

but it shows the max value because of the aggregate function

Comment: If you do **not** want to combine all the rows for a week into a single "group", then why are you pivoting the result of your initial subquery? Pivot against the table as is; the `seq` column will do the same job as the `row_number` in the accepted answer, and with far less work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function in order to group by that such as

```
SELECT "2101","2102","2103","2104","2105"
  FROM(
       SELECT TO_CHAR(dt,'dd') AS dt, work_week, 
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY work_week ORDER BY dt)
         FROM rp_calender
        WHERE TO_CHAR(dt,'yyyy') = '2021'
       )
 PIVOT ( MAX(dt) FOR work_week IN (2101,2102,2103,2104,2105) )
```

Comment: Much simpler: just preserve the `seq` in the OP's original table for pivoting. No need for a subquery, or `row_number()`.